# UML - Composição ou Agregação

Tags: java, uml

A 'Composição' relacionada nas classes 'controlaCurso' com a 'Curso' é realizado desta forma? Estou em dúvida se seria uma 'Composição' ou 'Agregação', ou nenhuma delas.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não existe somente uma resposta sempre correta nesse caso. Tudo vai depender da regra de negócio, de como deve ser estruturado.

- Se a sua regra de negócio especifica que `controleCurso` **DEVE TER** um `curso`, não podendo existir sem um, então é uma **COMPOSIÇÃO** (Assim como vc fez na imagem);
- Se a sua regra de negócio especifica que `controleCurso` **PODE TER OU NÃO** um `curso`, podendo existir com ou sem um, então é uma **AGREGAÇÃO**;

Tendo em vista os modelos apresentados na imagem, eu deixaria como composição tbm. Pois não faz sentido existir um registro de `controleCurso` com os campos apresentados, sem existir um curso para que ele possa relacionar. São informações necessárias para que ele exista.

Da uma olhada nesse site, ele tem mais detalhes e exemplos: https://www.ateomomento.com.br/uml-diagrama-de-classes/